# chown illegal group name (mac os x)

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, chown

I'm trying to run the following command in Terminal:

```
chown -R couchdb:couchdb /usr/local/var/log/couchdb
```

However, I keep getting this message:

```
chown: couchdb: illegal group name
```

I am using mac osx (mountain lion) and I have command line tools installed. I really don't know very much about unix, but I've been googling the illegal group name error and haven't turned up anything that would help. What am I overlooking? Any additional resources you think might be helpful also appreciated.

Comment: The `couchdb` group doesn't exist. Create it.

Comment: to see which group does the user `couchdb` belong to, type `id couchdb`

Comment: `/usr/local/var/log/couchdb` suggests you're logging in `/usr/local/`.  Not very usual.  (This has nothing to do with the non-existent group, though.)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`illegal group name` actually means that the group you're specifying (the `couchdb` after the colon -- the first `couchdb` is the user) doesn't exist.  You need to either create the group, stop specifying a group, or specify a group that exists.

Comment: Thanks for your help - went back to look at this code from way back to see what I ended up doing. Seems like I omitted the couchdb:couchdb part (since the log is in that location and working properly). So if anyone else is looking:      chown -R username  /usr/local/var/log/couchdb

Comment: If you don't want to create group then just do `sudo chown -R <username>: /usr/local/var/log/couchdb` form @jackotonye's answer.

Answer (score 79):

Try using just the owner if no group.

```
sudo chown -R user: /usr/local/var/log/couchdb
```

Comment: thank you! sorry for the late response - very much appreciate this.

Comment: there was $ sign before my username it worked when I deleted the sign. you may also see your user name on top of the terminal window.