# chgrp: apache illegal group name error in Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, apache, chgrp

I'm running `chgrp apache session` command to make sure that my php session directory has apache write permissions but I am getting the error: chgrp: apache illegal group name.

I am following a set of instructions for this. The next step says to execute `chmod g+wrx session` to finish checking that it has write permissions.

Another StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980675/chown-illegal-group-name-mac-os-x) said: "illegal group name actually means that the group you're specifying doesn't exist. You need to either create the group, stop specifying a group, or specify a group that exists."

Unfortunately I'm not well-versed with Linux commands so I'm not sure how to do any of those. I followed this tutorial: http://fideloper.com/user-group-permissions-chmod-apache to set up apache and it worked when I substituted '_www' for user and group and used /Library/Webserver/Documents as the document root.

I don't know if that is the equivalent of executing 'chgrp apache session' and 'chmod g+wrx session' so would appreciate any clarification there. I also want to know how to set up those groups because some of the further instructions rely on them so I'd appreciate any help with that.

The 'session' that is referred to is likely the      `session.save_path="/private/var/tmp"` that is the default session directory for OS X indicated in its php.ini file.

Would appreciate any clarification and advice on resolving this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

all groups are listed in /etc/group
you can see it's content by running less /etc/group

You can also see what process are running and who is running a process by looking at ps aux command.

It also is listed in httpd.conf (/etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf)

also in your question you mentioned the answer ("'_www' for user and group"), group is the same in both places.