# iOS archiving Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am using react native to develop my first cross-platform app. On my attempts to archive it, I encounter, the following error. I think it only happens in yoga library(?) or something. The error lies under yoga in the left pane...

```
Showing Recent Errors Only
SetOwnerAndGroup username:domänen-benutzer /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactHandHeld-asokbujgobowgaaaypozpydvtdur/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ReactHandHeld/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libyoga.a
    cd /Users/username/ReactHandHeld/node_modules/react-native/React
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/sbin/chown -RH username:domänen-benutzer /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactHandHeld-asokbujgobowgaaaypozpydvtdur/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ReactHandHeld/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libyoga.a

chown: domänen-benutzer: illegal group name
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chown illegal group name (mac os x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980675/chown-illegal-group-name-mac-os-x)

Comment: try not to use german umlauts for your groupNames [assuming you somehow made that usergroup on osx?] 

-- if thats not it post a minimal example app we can use to try out the issue

Answer (score 17):

I had exactly the same issue, I never created any group with german special characters (umlauts), I spent some time trying to figure out where the folder is located on disk or in the project but in vain, then I deleted derived data, cleaned the project, restarted Xcode and everything was working again.

Comment: Clearing the build directory and restarting the Xcode helped. Thank you so much!